# Select all files in all directories ending with specific names in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a lot of csv files which are saved in multiple directories. I would like to select names which ends with specific name such as "DWA日本語の名前).csv". Note that the name contains both english and Japanese characters.

```
path => "/mnt/resource2/sgsystem/20160206-4/**/*\"DWA日本語の名前).csv"
```

This is part of input plugin to export data to elasticsearch. It does not throw an error, but the data are not exported to elasticsearch. However, when I replace the Japanese characters (DWA日本語の名前) with English characters(e.g., DWAjapanese.csv), it works properly.
Any clue what is wrong here.

Comment: it's possible that elasticsearch just doesn't support japanese out of the box. looks like there's some sort of [japanese plugin for it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-kuromoji) though

Comment: It does support Japanese because when I do not include filename and just export all files, it does export all the files even with Japanese names. However, I want to select specific files to do other operations before exporting.

Comment: @NatheerAlabsi: Is really the double-quote also part of the filename? In particular, it looks odd that you are expecting a double-quote in the middle of a filename. But if it is so, can you try a `File.exist?` in Ruby on one certain file and check, whether Ruby finds it?

Comment: It is not part of the file name, I used the quotation there to select part of the file name.